# Is it possible to create a responsive webpart?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, css, html, responsive

I am creating a page on our SharePoint site and I'm having a problem on creating a responsive site because of the fixed values of a web part or a script editor. My question is, it is possible to create a responsive web part (bamboo world clock) and also I embed an iframe which is not accepted in the Edit source on the page so I insert it using a script editor. I can resize both web part and script editor but I can't seem to make it responsive.

Answer (score 1):

The responsive designing of SharePoint requires redesigning of all components in page life cycle. We have created for SharePoint 2013/2016 and SharePoint Online. The approach would be as follows

Choose CSS framework which supports responsive design. You can take one from the below listed.

1. Bootstrap
2. CSS Foundation
3. Fabric UI (Which is new by Microsoft)

Development approach

1. Create a custom master page (The responsive framework CSS files should be referred in the master page).
2. Create custom responsive page layouts. All the publishing pages should use these customs layouts.
3. Build responsive web parts.

The approach makes your complete site responsive works for any device and any browser.

Answer (score 0):

It's a pretty challenging task, so perhaps check out [responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com](http://responsivesharepoint.codeplex.com), which has a wsp you can install where others have already done all the work for you.